# Recursion in jQuery - Numerology

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I'm trying to get a recursive function to work in jQuery but I'm getting the following exception:

'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'

My understanding is that the recursive function must somehow be running infinitely but I can't work out why that's happening. Thanks...

```
jQuery.fn.reduceNumber = function(numberToReduce) {
if (numberToReduce < 10 || numberToReduce == 11 || numberToReduce == 22 || numberToReduce == 33){
    return numberToReduce;
} else {
    var newNumberToReduce =  numberToReduce.toString().substring(0,1) +   numberToReduce.toString().substring(1,2);
    return ($(this).reduceNumber(newNumberToReduce));
}   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#foo").html($(this).reduceNumber(12));
});
```

Comment: In what way should the number be reduced? Right now the only reducing the method does is getting the first two digits if the number has three digits or more. The strange way that you do that suggests that something else was actually intended.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are stuck in an infinite loop. You are calling `reduceNumber(12)`. Since it does not match the first `if()` statement, it goes to the second:

```
var newNumberToReduce =  numberToReduce.toString().substring(0,1) +   numberToReduce.toString().substring(1,2);
```

Leading `newNumberToReduce` to be.... `12`! Which then calls `reduceNumber(12)`, which does the same thing again and again and again, until the maximum stack size is exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

When you call reduceNumber the first time and pass 12

It goes to the function

It isn't smaller than 10, or equals to 11 or 22 or 33

So does the else

The newNumberToReduce is the first character of 12 (1) and second character of 12 (2)

So newNumberToReduce is 12

Calls the reduceNumber function again passing in 12 (again)

Therefore infinte loop

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
var newNumberToReduce =  numberToReduce.toString().substring(0,1) +   numberToReduce.toString().substring(1,2);
```

to this:

```
var newNumberToReduce =  (numberToReduce.toString().substring(0,1) | 0) +   (numberToReduce.toString().substring(1,2) | 0);
```

that will create a new number combined from your digits (1 + 2 = 3)